# Powerpoint master page with default content

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am working on a presentation where I need to reuse a slide with the same content multiple times. It is an outline page that contains a list of all the sections in my presentation. e.g.

- Introduction
- Previous Work
- ...
- Conclusion

I don't want to copy paste the same slide over and over again, and if I decided to change the outline (remove a section or edit a title), I will have to modify at least 10 slides. So I thought I could create a master page. But the problem is that it only keeps the first item in the list as a placeholder. I need a master slide that keeps content as well. Or is there a different way of doing that?

Comment: Repeating the same content on 10 slides makes for a boring presentation. You should think about restructuring it in a different way so you don't have to repeat stuff.

Comment: In my case I have to.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might consider doing, if you truly needed to do this, is making an image from the slide, and inserting that image (as a link) into all of the locations you need it to appear.  Then you can update the slide that image comes from, and then save that as an image file, allowing you to link to it.

You also could insert linked text (as a link to a Word document), a table from an Excel file, or several other filetypes that you can link to, and then just maintain that linked document.  An outline might be particularly suited to that feature.

---

As far as design goes, if you're going to have a repeated slide showing where in your presentation you are (the outline/ToC), you should probably on each slide highlight in some obvious color/fill/outline/etc. which part of the outline you are on; so you may not want to actually repeat the identical slide.  It's much better to do this so it's more obvious to the crowd where you are in the outline rather than repeating the identical outline.